# python how to manage variables between multiple threads

Tags: python, multithreading, mutex, semaphore, stock

I have create a stock market program which consists of multiple threads.
Each thread can perform function of placing order when a condition is met.
There are times when same condition is in 2 or more threads.
My problem is broker my doesn't allow more than 3 orders per second.
So if threads simultaneously place orders they get rejected
Need help

```
#get broker object
kite=get_kite()

def place_order():
    pass

def entry():
    while True:
        #scans for condition 
        if condition:
            place_order()
        
for i in range (0,10):
    thread = threading.Thread(target = self.entry)
    thread.start()
```

I tried using semaphore but didnt succeed

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Do some research. If you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [snippet editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: Please also check [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Your code does not show any effort of solving your described problem. What have you tried so far?

Comment: You're definitely going to have to write some code for that

Comment: This is what `threading.Lock()` is for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are seeking to `Lock()` the critical section of code.  Try:

```py
import threading
import random
import time

condition = True
lock = threading.Lock()

def entry():
    global condition

    while True:
        with lock:
            if condition:
                print("Placing Order")
                condition = random.random() < 0.8
            else:
                break
        time.sleep(0.1)

    print("Aborting")

for i in range (0, 10):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=entry)
    thread.start()
    thread.join()
```

That you give you something that looks like:

```
Placing Order
Placing Order
Placing Order
Placing Order
Placing Order
Placing Order
Aborting
Aborting
Aborting
Aborting
Aborting
Aborting
Aborting
Aborting
Aborting
Aborting
```

Hopefully that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes it works correctly  while sending 3 orders per second. However while placing order sometimes my broker takes too much time to respond and even the response gets stuck. How shall I handle such event

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-function-call how how you might timeout a method that runs too long.